# Cannot convert .List<string> to string

Tags: c#, string, list

Not sure what I am doing wrong here. I selected date data from an sql server using the select statement below. I then wanted to add it to a list. I have checked the datatype using System.Type and it tells me the values I'm getting back are System.String. So I thought this should be able to add it to a list of type String but I keep getting the error:

Cannot implicitly convert type `System.Collections.Generic.List<string>` to `string`

```
public String getListFromColumnAsDATE(String columnName, String database)
{
    myCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT [Date] = convert(char(10), getdate(), 103) FROM Weekly_Tannery_Data", myConnection);
    List<String> graphList = new List<String>();
    myConnection.Open();

    myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();

    while (myReader.Read())
    {
        graphList.Add(myReader.GetString(0));
    }

    myConnection.Close();
    return graphList;
}
```

Comment: Maybe bc your return type is String and you're returning a `List<String>`?

Comment: If you need a string, you should add the result from db into a `stringbuilder` and then do a `tostring`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reason behind this error comes from the fact that you have a return value of type `List<String>` when your method declaration says it should return a `String`.

The compiler is informing you that it can't convert an object of type `List` with the deferred type `String` into a `String`. This is normal because it has no way of doing so on its own. Depending on your context, you either need to switch the return value type in the declaration of the method as below or convert your list into a string like canon was suggesting.

```
public List<String> getListFromColumnAsDATE(String columnName, String database)
{
        myCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT [Date] = convert(char(10), getdate(), 103) FROM Weekly_Tannery_Data", myConnection);
        List<String> graphList = new List<String>();
        myConnection.Open();
        myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
        while (myReader.Read())
        {
            graphList.Add(myReader.GetString(0));
        }
        myConnection.Close();
        return graphList;
}
```

---

**Little side note:**

I would humbly suggest adding a using statement for your `SqlCommand` and the reader (`myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();`) since they implement `IDisposable`.

Comment: Ahh that was obvious. How stupid of me. Thank you so much Alerty.